# In array of TextViews, only the last TextView displayed

Tags: android, arrays, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to display an array of TextViews, but only the last TextView is displaying. I've checked moving the constraint margin according to the i value and found that they are not on top of one another.... only the last one is being displayed. Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

```
int baseID = 123;
ConstraintLayout parent = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_activity_view);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView[] TV = new TextView[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    TV[i] = new TextView(this);

    TV[i].setId(baseID + i);
    TV[i].setLayoutParams(params);
    TV[i].setText("TEST TEXT "+i);
    parent.addView(TV[i]);

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(parent);

    constraintSet.connect(TV[i].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.topTV, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    if (i > 0) constraintSet.connect(TV[i].getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, TV[i - 1].getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.applyTo(parent);
}
```

Comment: I think you should write constraintSet.applyTo(parent) outside of the loop.

Comment: @sapanravani took `ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();` above the forloop and took `constraintSet.applyTo(parent);` below, and now I don't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by placing `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` inside the for loop. Final code is as follows:

```
int baseID = 123;
ConstraintLayout parent = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_activity_view);

TextView[] TV = new TextView[5];
for (int i = 0; i < CueList.length; i++) {

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TV[i] = new TextView(this);

    TV[i].setId(baseID + i);
    TV[i].setLayoutParams(params);
    TV[i].setText("TEST TEXT "+i);
    parent.addView(TV[i]);

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(parent);

    constraintSet.connect(TV[i].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.cuelist, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    if (i > 0) constraintSet.connect(TV[i].getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, TV[i - 1].getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.applyTo(parent);
}
```